# Facebook Messenger SDK to share app Invite to Friends iOS

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-messenger

In my app i need to invite the facebook friends to download an application with Facebook Messenger, i am able to share image, gif, video .

How can i share text of link to download application from Messenger ?

The code i use to share image is :

```
if ([FBSDKMessengerSharer messengerPlatformCapabilities] & FBSDKMessengerPlatformCapabilityImage) {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Deepika-Padukone.png"];

    [FBSDKMessengerSharer shareImage:image withOptions:nil];

}
```

Help me out please !

Comment: Hi, Were you able to find a working solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you exactly want to do, but it seems you might be confused.

The `FBSDKMessengerSharer` lets you share content *from* your app, *into* Messenger. The content can be (animated) images, audio and video. So for example: if you have an app with images, you can let somebody share that image with somebody else, via Messenger.

The `FBSDKMessengerSharer` *does not* let you share applications/download links. For that, you can use [App Requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/app-request) or [Game Requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.3).

On the other hand, the [Messenger API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger/overview) lets you share and reply content from *within* Messenger. Your application can share to Messenger and people will be able to,

1. Reply with your app, If they have installed the app as well,
2. Install the App, if they not have done so yet.

These kind of apps are typically "reaction" apps; (animated) images that are nice in chat-threads.

I hope this clarifies the possibilities for you.

Comment: Thanks .. so if i need to invite a user to download my app , i need to use app invites ? right ?

Comment: Yes, that would be one of the options. Or the Game Request dialog (which also works for non-game Apps).

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to "Accept" the answer if it is correct and helps you :)